# How to resolve "invalid property name" error to make file chooser with kivy?

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, image, kivy

I am new to kivy and am trying to build an application in which I have three tabs: one for loading the image, another for displaying the image and a grayscale version side by side, and finally, one tab for only showing the grayscale image.

I have got the following from [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6x1gUNoVB2I) and hope to use this for python 3, but I have repeatedly received the error below.

> Invalid property name

This is the code I am currently using:

```
import kivy; 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from PIL import*

Builder.load_string("""
<RootWidget>:
 manager:manager
 img:img
 img3:img3
 img4:img4
 lab:lab
 do_default_tab:False
 ScreenManager:
    id:manager
    Screen:
        id:sc1
        name:'Load img'
        FileChooserIconView
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb:0.5, 0.4, 0.5
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size: self.size
            on_selection:root.select_to(*args)
    Screen:
        id:sc2
        name:'Image'
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                id:lab
                pos_hint:{"right": 0.55, 'top': 1}
                size_hint:.15,0.1

        RelativeLayout:
            Image:
                id:img
                on_touch_down:str('Relative:{}'.format(args[1].pos))
                post_hint:{"left": 1, 'bottom': 1}
                size_hint:0.5, 1
                allow_strech:True
        RelativeLayout:
            Image:
                id:img3
                post_hint:{"right": 1, 'bottom': 1}
                size_hint:0.5, 1
                allow_strech = True
        Screen:
            id:sc3
            name:'Image_'
            FloatLayout:
                Image:
                    id:img4
                    keep_data:True
                    post:self.pos
                    size: self.size
    TabbedPanelHeader:
        text.sc1.name
        background_color: 1,0,0,1
        screen:sc1.name
    TabbedPanelHeader:
        text:sc2.name
        background_color: 1,1,0,1
        screen:sc2.name
    TabbedPanelHeader:
        text:sc3.name
        background_color: 1,0,1,1
        screen:sc3.name
""")

class RootWidget(TabbedPanel):

 manager = ObjectProperty(None)

 def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if not self.img3.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        return True
    else:
        self.lab.text ='Pos: (%d,%d)' %(touch.x, touch.y)
        return True

 def switch_to(self, header):    
    # set the Screen manager to load  the appropriate screen
    # linked to the tab head instead of loading content
    self.manager.current = header.screen
    # we have to replace the functionality of the original switch_to
    self.current_tab.state = "normal"
    header.state = 'down'
    self._current_tab = header
 def select_to(self, *args):
    try:
        print(args[1][0])
        iw = Image.open(args[1][0])
        iw.save('./phase.jpg')
        gray = iw.convert('1')
        gray.save('.gray_im.jpg')
        self.img3.source = './gray_im.jpg'
        self.img4.source = './gray_im.jpg'
        self.img.source = './phase.jpg'
        self.img.reload()
        self.img3.reload()
        self.img4.reload()
    except:
        pass

 def update_touch_lavel(self, label, touch):
    label.text = 'Pos:(%d, %d)' % (touch.x, touch.y)
    label.texture_update()
    label.pos = touch.pos
    label.size = label.texture_size[0] + 20, label.texture_size[1] + 20

class MainApp(App):
 title = 'Screen Widget'
 def build(self):
    return RootWidget()
 def on_pause(self):
    return True

if __name__ == '__main___':
  MainApp().run()
```

I am unsure why I am receiving this error. I would greatly appreciate some help to fix the code to work as intended.

Comment: You can improve the identation of your code, it's horrible.

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry, the formatting of code gets messed up when copying and pasting the code from my editor? Is there another way you would like me to share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the example for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from PIL import Image


class RootWidget(TabbedPanel):
    manager = ObjectProperty(None)
    img = ObjectProperty(None)
    img3 = ObjectProperty(None)
    img4 = ObjectProperty(None)
    lab = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if not self.img3.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return True
        else:
            self.lab.text = 'Pos: (%d,%d)' % (touch.x, touch.y)
            return True

    def switch_to(self, header):
        # set the Screen manager to load  the appropriate screen
        # linked to the tab head instead of loading content
        self.manager.current = header.screen

        # we have to replace the functionality of the original switch_to
        self.current_tab.state = "normal"
        header.state = 'down'
        self._current_tab = header

    def select_to(self, *args):
        try:
            print(args[1][0])
            iw = Image.open(args[1][0])
            iw.save('./phase.jpg')
            gray = iw.convert('1')
            gray.save('./gray_im.jpg')
            self.img3.source = './gray_im.jpg'
            self.img4.source = './gray_im.jpg'
            self.img.source = './phase.jpg'
            self.img.reload()
            self.img3.reload()
            self.img4.reload()
        except:
            pass

    def update_touch_label(self, label, touch):
        label.text = 'Pos:(%d, %d)' % (touch.x, touch.y)
        label.texture_update()
        label.pos = touch.pos
        label.size = label.texture_size[0] + 20, label.texture_size[1] + 20


class TestApp(App):
    title = 'Screen Widget'

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

    def on_pause(self):
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<RootWidget>:
    manager: manager
    img: img
    img3: img3
    img4: img4
    lab: lab
    do_default_tab: False

    ScreenManager:
        id: manager

        Screen:
            id: sc1
            name:'Load img'

            FileChooserIconView:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0.5, 0.4, 0.5
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                on_selection:
                    root.select_to(*args)

        Screen:
            id: sc2
            name: 'Image'

            FloatLayout:
                Button:
                    id: lab
                    pos_hint: {"right": 0.55, 'top': 1}
                    size_hint: .15,0.1

            RelativeLayout:
                Image:
                    id: img
                    on_touch_down:
                        str('Relative:{}'.format(args[1].pos))
                    pos_hint: {"left": 1, 'bottom': 1}
                    size_hint: 0.5, 1
                    allow_stretch: True

            RelativeLayout:
                Image:
                    id: img3
                    pos_hint: {"right": 1, 'bottom': 1}
                    size_hint: 0.5, 1
                    allow_stretch: True

        Screen:
            id: sc3
            name: 'Image_'

            FloatLayout:
                Image:
                    id: img4
                    keep_data: True
                    post: self.pos
                    size: self.size

    TabbedPanelHeader:
        text: sc1.name
        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        screen: sc1.name

    TabbedPanelHeader:
        text: sc2.name
        background_color: 1, 1, 0, 1
        screen: sc2.name

    TabbedPanelHeader:
        text: sc3.name
        background_color: 1, 0, 1, 1
        screen: sc3.name
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]

Comment: Thank you very much! Much appreciated!

Comment: I would like to request your help with another task. Could you help me make a folder selector instead of a file selector?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294999/how-to-select-multiple-files-with-filechooser-with-kivy