# How to select multiple files with FileChooser with Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am using kivy and python to build an application.

I am trying to build an application in which I can select several images, add them to an array, and then pass this array of images through another method which stitches the images (using the stitcher class). The output image will display on one of the three screens (also I want to remove the middle screen).

So essentially what I would like help with is how to be able to select multiple files with filechooser in kivy and then add these files to array that I can later pass through a different method.

With the help of @ikolim in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279247/how-to-resolve-invalid-property-name-error-to-make-file-chooser-with-kivy/51291149#51291149), I have been able to create the application.

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from PIL import Image


class RootWidget(TabbedPanel):
    manager = ObjectProperty(None)
    img = ObjectProperty(None)
    img3 = ObjectProperty(None)
    img4 = ObjectProperty(None)
    lab = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if not self.img3.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return True
        else:
            self.lab.text = 'Pos: (%d,%d)' % (touch.x, touch.y)
            return True

    def switch_to(self, header):
        # set the Screen manager to load  the appropriate screen
        # linked to the tab head instead of loading content
        self.manager.current = header.screen

        # we have to replace the functionality of the original switch_to
        self.current_tab.state = "normal"
        header.state = 'down'
        self._current_tab = header

    def select_to(self, *args):
        try:
            print(args[1][0])
            iw = Image.open(args[1][0])
            iw.save('./phase.jpg')
            gray = iw.convert('1')
            gray.save('./gray_im.jpg')
            self.img3.source = './gray_im.jpg'
            self.img4.source = './gray_im.jpg'
            self.img.source = './phase.jpg'
            self.img.reload()
            self.img3.reload()
            self.img4.reload()
        except:
            pass

    def update_touch_label(self, label, touch):
        label.text = 'Pos:(%d, %d)' % (touch.x, touch.y)
        label.texture_update()
        label.pos = touch.pos
        label.size = label.texture_size[0] + 20, label.texture_size[1] + 20


class TestApp(App):
    title = 'Screen Widget'

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

    def on_pause(self):
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**Test.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<RootWidget>:
    manager: manager
    img: img
    img3: img3
    img4: img4
    lab: lab
    do_default_tab: False

    ScreenManager:
        id: manager

        Screen:
            id: sc1
            name:'Load img'

            FileChooserIconView:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0.5, 0.4, 0.5
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                on_selection:
                    root.select_to(*args)

        Screen:
            id: sc2
            name: 'Image'

            FloatLayout:
                Button:
                    id: lab
                    pos_hint: {"right": 0.55, 'top': 1}
                    size_hint: .15,0.1

            RelativeLayout:
                Image:
                    id: img
                    on_touch_down:
                        str('Relative:{}'.format(args[1].pos))
                    pos_hint: {"left": 1, 'bottom': 1}
                    size_hint: 0.5, 1
                    allow_stretch: True

            RelativeLayout:
                Image:
                    id: img3
                    pos_hint: {"right": 1, 'bottom': 1}
                    size_hint: 0.5, 1
                    allow_stretch: True

        Screen:
            id: sc3
            name: 'Image_'

            FloatLayout:
                Image:
                    id: img4
                    keep_data: True
                    post: self.pos
                    size: self.size

    TabbedPanelHeader:
        text: sc1.name
        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        screen: sc1.name

    TabbedPanelHeader:
        text: sc2.name
        background_color: 1, 1, 0, 1
        screen: sc2.name

    TabbedPanelHeader:
        text: sc3.name
        background_color: 1, 0, 1, 1
        screen: sc3.name
```

Comment: Thanks for asking this, I have the same question! Hopefully we get a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that does what I think you want:

```
import os

import kivy
from kivy import platform
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import kivy.garden.filebrowser


class FileBrowserApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = FloatLayout()
        button = Button(text='Select Files', pos_hint={'x':0, 'y': 0}, size_hint=(0.2, 0.1))
        button.bind(on_press=self.do_select)
        self.root.add_widget(button)
        return self.root

    def do_select(self, *args):
        homeDir = None
        if platform == 'win':
            homeDir = os.environ["HOMEPATH"]
        elif platform == 'android':
            homeDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        elif platform == 'linux':
            homeDir = os.environ["HOME"]
        self.fbrowser = kivy.garden.filebrowser.FileBrowser(select_string='Select',
            multiselect=True, filters=['*.png'], path=homeDir)
        self.root.add_widget(self.fbrowser)
        self.fbrowser.bind(
            on_success=self._fbrowser_success,
            on_canceled=self._fbrowser_canceled,
            on_submit=self._fbrowser_success)

    def _fbrowser_success(self, fbInstance):
        if len(fbInstance.selection) == 0:
            return
        selected = []
        for file in fbInstance.selection:
            selected.append(os.path.join(fbInstance.path, file))
        print('selected: ' + str(selected))
        self.root.remove_widget(self.fbrowser)
        self.fbrowser = None

    def _fbrowser_canceled(self, instance):
        self.root.remove_widget(self.fbrowser)
        self.fbrowser = None

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = FileBrowserApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but this does not seem to work for me.

Comment: It shows as [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tzMZcYtgjdbM8UIgzGnUDIamrLUY2_uI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sorry, didn't think I needed to mention, but click on 'Select Files'.

Comment: When I do click on 'Select Files' I recieve [this error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nQvVQsZ9Y_ASbcDyzPOWqI-HekfeL0eQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What os are you running? The code should work for Linux, Windows, or Android, but not MacOS. Try deleting the `, path=homeDir` on the continuation line for `self.fbrowser=`.

Comment: Thank you very much, will I be able to deploy this app to ios?

Comment: Also, I have a method called stitch() that takes a array of images, where would I put this method for this code?

Comment: Also, how would I make another screeen that displays the resulting image of the stitch() method?

Comment: Technically, I should tell you to open a new `StackOverflow` question for each of those question. But briefly, you can put the `stitch()` method anywhere you like (maybe in a new class that handles your images). You can display your image result many different ways, `ScreenManager`, `ModalView`, and `Popup` are the ones that occur to me first. As far as IOS goes, have a look at [Create a package for IOS](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html). I personally have no experience with IOS.

Answer (score 4):

In your Test.kv file, after FileChooserIconView:  add multiselect: True

```
FileChooserIconView:
    multiselect: True
```

This will allow the selection of multiple files.

If you use FileChooserListView instead of FileChooserIconView, the file chooser window will not discriminate selected/not selected files visually. You can still select multiple files, but you need to remember the selected files. The first click selects and the second click deselects. I hope the developers of this widget will correct this issue soon.